# Unwrapping with unwrap function

Tags: matlab

I have  wrapped phases and I want to unwrap them using the function "wrap". However, in this case I can't get the unwrapped phases for  reasons unclear to me.

The wrapped phases are [image]

and by looking at the cross section I can see that the phases are wrapped

I have scaled the image to be from 0 to 2*pi by:

```
ScaledWrapped = Wrapped*7*2*pi;
```

[image]

When applying the function unwrap:

```
UnwrappedImage = unwrap(ScaledWrapped);
```

I don't get unwrapped phases and I don't know why. The result is :

[image]

and I don't know what's going wrong!

Any suggestions please!!

Many thanks in advance

Comment: what is the range of Scaled wrapped, it looks like it is greater than 0:2*pi.

Comment: `unwrap()` works columnwise: are you trying to unwrap rows? It's difficult to tell in the absence of data

Comment: Indeed, try `unwrap(ScaledWrapped,[],2)`

Comment: Whence the scale factor of 7? To us, it just a magic number that drops out of the sky...

Comment: The scale of 7 because it is 7 areas with each one is from 0 to 0.14 and with this scaling it goes to 2 Pi

Comment: the solution that Rody gave looks ok  and I think it is the same idea as Max said that unwrap() works columnwise

Comment: the more general case for scaling anything is `thing/max(thing(:))*scaling` where, here `scaling = 2*pi`

Comment: @Jack_111 And does the solution of Rody work? Should he make an answer from it?

Answer (score 2):

Your data may not have proper jumps. From `help unwrap`:  unwrap(P) unwraps radian phases P by changing **absolute jumps greater than or equal to pi** to their `2*pi` complement.

See how bad scaling of data (compare `y` and `y1`) results in different unwrapped data:

```
x = linspace(0,pi,20)';
y = [x;x;x;x;x;];
y1 = 1.1*y;
plot(y,'ro'); hold on; plot(unwrap(y)); hold on; plot(unwrap(y1))
```

[image]